# EXT js grid having one column of radio buttons

Tags: extjs

I have an ext js grid like below:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
columns: [
{header: 'Account Id',dataIndex:'accountId' },
{header: 'Account NUmber',dataIndex:'accountNumber' }
]
})
```

Now I need to show Account Id column as a column of radio buttons. So from the grid user can select one Account Id and submit. When the user reloads the page, that account id should be preselected.

I need some help on how to proceed on this. Do I need to write a renderer on Account Id column? Or is there an easier way.

EDIT: I did like this:

```
{header: 'Account Id',dataIndex:'accountId',renderer: function(value) {
return "<input type='radio' name = 'primaryRadio' " + (value ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
 }},
```

What is the syntax to add an onclick event or onchange event to the radio group?

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so I can accept ?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did well on showing Account Id column as a column of radio buttons, by using a renderer function.

Regarding the onclick event for these, you may simply add the onclick attribute in the HTML tag:

```
return "<input onclick='my_function()' type='radio' name = 'primaryRadio' " + (value ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
```

Answer (score 8):

Building off the previous answer, yes, I think using a renderer for your column is the correct solution.  I think you should go about the click event differently than J. Bruni suggested though.  I'd recommend a click listener on your grid panel that checks if you clicked a radio button, and delegates to a method in your GridPanel.

Something like this:

```
MyRadioGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    columns: [
        {header: 'Account Id',dataIndex:'accountId', renderer: function(value) {
            return "<input type='radio' name = 'primaryRadio' " + (value ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
        }},
        {header: 'Account NUmber',dataIndex:'accountNumber' }
    ],

    afterRender: function() {
        MyRadioGrid.superclass.afterRender.apply(this, arguments);
        this.el.on('click', this.checkRadioClick, this);
    },

    checkRadioClick: function(event) {
        if (event.getTarget('input[type="radio"]')) {
            //radio clicked... do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 This is better than setting `onclick` in every element. It only seemed a bit verbose... Do we have a shorter/cleaner way to attach the event handler? Something like jQuery's `$('#grid').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', callback);` or `$('input.account_id').click(callback);` (assuming we added an 'account_id' class to the inputs)...

Comment: Yeah, jQuery does a lot with little code :).  In this example, though, and in general with Ext, it's best to wrap your business components as classes that extend the Ext component, which is the bulk of the code I wrote above.  The shorter version, without creating a  whole class, would just be something like `myGrid.el.on('click', functionToCheckForRadio)`, and then you would still need the `event.getTarget` logic.  I don't know of any shorter-hand way in Ext of filtering events based on the target clicked, although that sounds like a nice extension!